# Do rail tickets to Jungfraujoch actually need to be printed?

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland

I want to buy tickets to Jungfraujoch with a seat reservation, but I'm already in Switzerland and thus don't have a printer. The website claims that they need to be printed, but is that *actually* the case in practice? Is showing them on a smartphone (or even an iPad if size matters) good enough?

Comment: If you staying at a hotel, ask the helpdesk. They might have a printer to print it on.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking about. Swiss Railways offers two kinds of internet tickets, an 'OnlineTicket', which must be printed, or a 'MobileTicket', which is stored on a smart-phone or tablet. Which web site are you referring to?

Comment: Barcodes etc are usually scannable from your phone, the question if it *actually* needs to be printed depends on the person checking your ticket I think. If they don't care, it's fine. But if they decide to stick to the rules, you might have trouble.

Comment: Might be due to the barcode reader:  http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/articles/reading_barcodes_directly_from_computer_screen

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Sticking to the rules? In Switzerland? Sounds unlikley. Next you'll be telling me that the train will probably be on time

Comment: @CMaster Great to see you're such an expert on Swiss stereotypes. Why don't you add an answer yourself?

Answer (score 8):

If you buy tickets from their website, then, *yes*, you have to print them. I was told by their customer service that you can print your tickets at the train station for 5 CHF.

But you can also buy tickets at [sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch) and in that case it is enough to show them on your phone.